# Doesn't show anything on folder vsftpd

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, centos, vsftpd

vsftpd.conf folder is

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=NO
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

I run the bash code like that

```
sudo chown  myftp:myftp /var/www/ -R
sudo chmod a+rwx  /var/www/
chmod 777 /var/www/
sudo chown -R myftp:myftp /var/www/
```

And passwd folder

```
myftp:x:1000:1001::/var/www/html:/bin/bash
```

I cant create folder or see any folder on FTP.

I can connect its fine.

My Server is Centos.

When i create a folder i get this error ;

```
553 Could not create file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config is wrong and unsafe

You should turn off SELinux

Or

You need to run the following commands to allow in SELinux upload and edit files:

setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access on
   setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on